# detect file extension in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do both python and node coding. I have a keybinding for console.log() in Visual Studio Code.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log('$0',)"
    }
  }
```

I want this same shortcut to detect the `.py` extension and print `print('',)` and detect `.js, .ts` file extension and print `console.log('',)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == javascript",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log('$0',)"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == typescript",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log('$0',)"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == python",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "print('$0',)"
    }
},
```